# How do I get same result using addEventListener (keyup) instead of onkeyup attribute in the HTML?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener, keyup, onkeyup

I want to restrict an input text through a regular expression. In the first example I use the attribute `onkeyup = "lettersOnly(this)"` inside the HTML, as follows:

```
<form>
<label for="username">Choose a Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" onkeyup="lettersOnly(this)">
</form>

<script>
function lettersOnly(input){
            var regex = /[^a-z]/gi;
            input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "");
        }
</script>
```

It works but I learnt that this is a **bad practice**. I found other solution avoiding that, and setting `someVariable.onkeyup` inside `<script>` tags. However, **my goal** is to find another way to get the same result using `addEventListener ('keyup', lettersOnly, false)`. I researched a lot for this specific situation but no answers. Is it possible? I tried the following:

```
<form>
<label for="username">Choose a Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
<!--No more “onkeyup” attribute.-->
</form>   

<script>
function lettersOnly(input){
        var regex = /[^a-z]/gi;
        input.value.addEventListener('keyup', lettersOnly(input){
        input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "");
          }, false)
        }
</script>
```

Doesn‘t work. My intention is to avoid the event handler in the html and use instead, the addEventListener. What is wrong in this last coding? Why doesn‘t work? I‘ll really appreciate your patience.

Comment: I just noticed in your second code block, you are adding an `eventListener` to `input.value` which will certainly not work and you will get an error stating `input.value.addEventListener is not a function`. It should be applied to the `input` element instead.

Answer (score 1):

In the code that you said you have tried; the function `lettersOnly()` will never be called and `addEventListener()` will never be called.

You can simply change it as follow -

```
<script>
    function lettersOnly(input){
        var regex = /[^a-z]/gi;
        input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "");
    }
    document.getElementById("username").addEventListener("keyup", lettersOnly(this), false);
</script>
```

Comment: Also doesn‘t work, sorry.

Comment: @limakid can you look at your browser console whether there is an error or not?

Comment: The console output is:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
    at lettersOnly (aa-keyup.html:15)
    at aa-keyup.html:17
lettersOnly @ aa-keyup.html:15
(anonymous) @ aa-keyup.html:17

Comment: Even though your comment didn‘t help me, going back to my original question, Why do you say that the function lettersOnly and the addEvent Listener will never be called? Something regarding the scope? the variables must be outside of the function? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This answer doesn't actually answer the question (at least, it doesn't attempt to explain how it does). Please provide supporting information in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found myself a solution and I want to share it.

```
<form>
<label for="username">Choose a Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
<!--No more “onkeyup” attribute.-->
</form>  
<script>
  let user = document.getElementById("username");
  var regex = /[^a-z]/gi;
   
  user.addEventListener("keyup", ()=>{
  user.value = user.value.replace(regex, "");
})
  // The “user” variable has been just to simplify a lot of repeated coding, as it is equivalent to “document.getElementById(“username”).
</script>
```

I don‘t know if this is the best and optimal way to solve my inquire but it works. No “ONkeyup” at all, but using, instead, `addEventListener ("keyup", anonymous arrow function)`. I‘ll really appreciate if anybody has any other suggestion.

Comment: Honestly, it looks like a decent solution. You could also use the `keydown` event and use [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) if the input is invalid (see [`.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) for specifics); this will simply prevent the input from changing if you would like. If you wanted advice on how to improve working code, you could also check out [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your second piece of code was that you weren't actually attaching the eventListener to the input element since the outer `lettersOnly` function was also not called at any time. It appears you resolved this in your own answer, but I'm going to expand upon my comment and suggest using [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event) instead.

In the following snippet, I changed the eventListener to attach to `keydown` instead of `keyup`. Then we test if the new key (via [`event.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)) matches our regex with [`.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match). If the key pressed is a non-letter character, the match will be non-null, so we want to utilize [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to interrupt the new key from being added to the input value.

**Note**: this has the added benefit of not needing to use `replace` or `replaceAll` to remove the invalid character.

```js
var regex = /[^a-z]/gi;

function lettersOnly(event) {
  if (event.key.match(regex) !== null) {
    // Since it is an invalid character, we will prevent default
    event.preventDefault();

    // Log the key to the console for demonstration
    console.log(event.key);

    // Not needed since we preventDefault()
    //event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(regex, "");
  }
}
// `username` is equivalent to `document.getElementById("username")
username.addEventListener("keydown", lettersOnly, false);
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="username">Choose a Username:</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
</form>
```